# After adding Anaconda to PATH, Jupyter Notebook not opening?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I followed the documentation for Anaconda, and I also selected Anaconda to ADD to PATH option during installation because I haven't installed Python before. While I have Anaconda in PATH, I still get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

In `cmd`, I started with `activate base` then `jupyter notebook`. That is my error. Here are all the path variables related to Anaconda:
[image]

This is what I get when I do `conda list`

```
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2019.07                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0
astropy                   3.2.1            py37he774522_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1
bitarray                  0.9.3            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
blosc                     1.16.3               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     1.2.0                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h452e1ab_1
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py37_0
conda                     4.7.10                   py37_0
conda-build               3.18.8                   py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.3.11                   py37_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0
cryptography              2.7              py37h7a1dbc1_0
curl                      7.65.2               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.12          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.1.0                      py_0
dask-core                 2.1.0                      py_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
distributed               2.1.0                      py_0
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.4.0            py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.5.0                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.17                     py37_1
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.0                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.8.4                      py_0
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
jupyterlab                1.0.2            py37hf63ae98_0
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hc04afaa_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libcurl                   7.65.2               h2a8f88b_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.2                h7a1dbc1_0
libtiff                   4.0.10               hb898794_2
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
libxslt                   1.1.33               h579f668_0
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.3.4            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.0            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.0.2            py37he774522_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0
more-itertools            7.0.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
networkx                  2.3                        py_0
nltk                      3.4.4                    py37_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  6.0.0                    py37_0
numba                     0.44.1           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.6.9            py37hdce8814_0
numpy                     1.16.4           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  2.6.2                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1
packaging                 19.0                     py37_0
pandas                    0.24.2           py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0
pathlib2                  2.3.4                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    6.1.0            py37hdc69c19_0
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0
psutil                    5.6.3            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37hfa6e2cd_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h1da0976_1
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                    py37_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py37_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_11
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h8c2d366_1
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1
qtconsole                 4.5.1                      py_0
qtpy                      1.8.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37ha925a31_0
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.2.1            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.5            py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.10.0           py37h8c2d366_0
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
tqdm                      4.32.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.0                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.1.8                      py_0
xlwings                   0.15.8                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      0.5.1                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Any Help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of research into your problem, it appears to be an issue with Anaconda and the built-in Python modules. Based on your error above it seems like there is an issue with your SSL module. I found the following link, hopefully it helps solve your problem.

To summarize the solution on the link here is what they recommend:

Copy the following files from `./Library/bin` too `./DLL/`:

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
- libssl-1_1-x64.*

Here is the link: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10576

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

cd into the directory you wish to start jupyter notebook from
then type the command conda run jupyter notebook